# How to select row with a largest value in its group?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table, contains a list of tasks:

```
ID      TaskName       Date
----------------------------------
1       Task1          2010-11-23
2       Task2          2011-12-01
3       Task1          2012-02-01
4       Task3          2008-01-09
5       Task2          2007-03-09
6       Task3          2000-01-01
```

how to create a view contain task with its lastest perform date?

e.g result from the above table should be:

```
id  taskname  date
------------------------
3   Task1     2012-02-01
2   Task2     2011-12-01
4   Task3     2008-01-09
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
  ID,
  TaskName,
  Date
FROM
(
  select 
    ID,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TaskName ORDER BY Date DESC) Ordinal,
    TaskName,
    Date
  FROM YourTable
) t
WHERE Ordinal = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, taskName, MAX(Date)
FROM table
GROUP BY taskName
```

(This will not work in Oracle because id is not in the GROUP BY)